# How could I make my website open in a specific port?

Tags: php, apache, web, port, ports

I own a website which is hosted on my windows machine. I have all the necessary software installed,like apache,php etc... I have created a sub-domain in freedns.afraid.org and I am using this instead of my IP.
 I have port forwarded on port 8080 so the page index.php will be shown only if someone open the website on port 8080
If someone open the website on port 80,which is the default,the page he will see is this: *http://prntscr.com/b7sttk*  but if he add in the address bar after the domain the :8080 he will see this: *http://prntscr.com/b7su47*  which is what I want the visitors to see.
So now the question,how could I make the website open automatically on port 8080 without typing every time (for example) domain.e-it.gr **:8080**
Is that possible? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a file index.php with :

```
 <?php 
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".":8080"."$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
header('Location: '.$actual_link);

?>
```

this file will redirect to  :8080 :)

or just :

```
<?php 
    $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".":8080";
    header('Location: '.$actual_link);

    ?>
```

Comment: Hey! I have no idea about php programming so I need more help. Do I have to change something in the code you posted? If I add the code to my index.php file,my localhost file redirects me successfully to the port 8080 but the page isn't loading and it say's "Corrupted Content Error". What's more the online page isn't redirecting to the 8080 port and if I try to enter to 8080 port manually it say's the same...

Comment: I update the post, try the second part, to add this in your index.php, if index also exists please send a part of exists code.

Comment: These are my files in www folder http://prnt.sc/b8b2xw
Here is my html file http://prnt.sc/b8b381
Here is my php file http://prnt.sc/b8b3f7
Here is the localhost,it redirects me to port 8080 but the html file is not displayed http://prnt.sc/b8b3mn
Here is the my subdomain,neither it redirects me to port 8080 nor it opens the html file http://prnt.sc/b8b3zf

Comment: try a look on your config apache : the folder of web site linked on the port 8080

Comment: you can allways add the port 80 on apache config : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/bind.html